# Using 500W to power a 4kW electric heating element

Tags: solar-energy, heater

I have a 120 liter water heater powered by a 4kW heating element. I own two 350W solar panels totalling ~700W out of which I expect to reliably draw ~500W of power.
I am looking for a way to take the 500W at 24V from the solar panels, raise the voltage with a DC-to-DC converter, store the energy in a capacitor and discharge at the rated power on the heating element.
So for every 8 seconds of charging, the heating element would work for 1 second.

Is anyone aware of any off-the-shelf module that would do this sort of thing?
What are my options to achieving this?

Comment: Why do you want to have an 8/1 second cycle? Or is that just an example? You could just power the heater with a DC to DC converter without storing power for so long.

Comment: Why a capacitor?  Use a large battery.  Let it charge all day, and you'll have enough energy to operate your water heater for a little while.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I don't wish to alter the heating element. I don't think I can just connect a 240v heating element to 24v as it won't heat up to the rated temperature.

Comment: @JRE There is no battery in the system, and there is no point in adding this cost if I am to convert the energy into heat anyway. Charging a capacitor has much less energy losses than charging a battery and then discharging it.

Comment: A capacitor large enough to do any good will be **much** bigger and **much** more expensive than a battery.

Comment: If all you want is hot water, look into a [solar collector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_thermal_collector) instead of photovoltaic cells.

Comment: Solar water heating is more effective than pv to heat when you want hot water.

Comment: @PaulB. You don't need to modify your heating element. See Neil_UK's answer. But if you want to have a duty cycle you could use 40 uSec cycle with 5 uSec on time, and get the same result but with a capacitor 1/200,000 the size.

Comment: Assuming these are standard resistive heaters, there is no need to raise the voltage, or store it for brief bursts.  Just feed the power in directly.

Comment: @JRE 1kw/s was an example. The point was that the charge time would be 8 times greater than the discharge. That could even be achieved with off the shelf power supply capacitors working in the millisecond range at a 8/1 charge discharge cycle. In any case, a good enough answer was provided and I will be trying it out this weekend.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy It was just an example. Yes, given the provided comments and answers, it appears that I can just raise the voltage with a dc-dc converter to ~80v and it should be good to go, which makes my life much easier. Will be trying this this weekend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a heating element of 4 kW at 230 V:

$$R=\dfrac{230^2}{4000}=13.2 \Omega$$
This heater would draw 500 W of power when voltage is \$V=\sqrt{P*R}\approx\sqrt{500*13.2}=81V\$

So you do need a boost converter. But you could also wire two panels in series.

[Example panel](https://www.enfsolar.com/pv/panel-datasheet/crystalline/43778)

[image: Table of example panel specifications]

Then you have a MPPT voltage at 38.5 X 2 = 77V, which is very close to your needs.

[MPPT Voltage VS. Irradiance](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Maximum-Power-Point-Tracking-(MPPT)-via-Weightless-Ting-Man/869071334074db0c16f9387c6ab2aaa65eadd1ec/figure/0)

[image: MPPT curve of example panel]

You can see that MPPT voltage doesn't change drastically. If your panels have similar characteristics, then you can simply connect them on the heater and you'll get the max. performance, because no extra converter losses would be involved.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have been looking for.

Comment: This correlates very well with what this guy did, maximum power point but without tracking. YouTube link: https://youtu.be/KVeGummoXS0

Comment: But also be aware that most heating elements have a positive temperature coefficient of resistance. This means that, for a lower voltage than would produce 4kW, the element will have a lower resistance than you expect. So, your voltage across the heater will be a bit lower than you expect.

Answer (score 11):

A 4 kW heating element doesn't have to work at 4 kW. It will produce 500 W average heat output whether it's driven at 100% of the time with 500 W, or for 12.5% of the time with 4 kW.

Use a DC to DC converter to produce the right voltage to drive the element at 500 W. You do not need to store energy in batteries or capacitors.

Better, if your panel controller MPPT will work with a resistive load, configure that to drive the heater.

Better still, absorb the sunlight directly into water heating tubes, you will get much higher water-heating efficiency than going via electricity.

Answer (score 3):

#### Frame Challenge

You are working on a complicated way to:

- Convert solar radiation (aka sunlight) to electricity, **typically at a rate of around 15% efficiency**
- Use the electricity to heat water at a low rate (i.e., much lower than the design capacity of the water heater)

Now if all this was essentially "free", it would be well worth it. But we're talking inverters, converters, batteries, capacitors, etc. Not free by any stretch. Plus the electricity generated is not available to run other things that *require* electricity - computers and other consumer electronics, fans, lights, etc.

On the other hand, if you use the solar radiation to *directly* heat the water, it is far more efficient. This does require some additional equipment - the solar collector and piping from/to the water heater. But it works. In fact, Israel (and I think some other countries too) use this for residential hot water on a regular basis. Then your solar panels are free to provide electricity for everything else.

This problem is not unique to solar energy. For example, "ordinary" electric heat (aka "giant toaster") is 100% efficient at converting electricity to heat, but the electricity is, in many places, generated very inefficiently from fossil fuels. In that situation, using natural gas to directly generate heat is much more efficient. (Leaving out the "heat pump" issue for the moment - that changes the equation in other ways.) This is *especially* the case if you use a generator for backup power - a home generator will generally be less efficient overall than a utility-scale generator, so using a generator to run electric heat will go through your gas a lot faster than the same gas burned to generate heat (with electricity just used for fan, controls, etc.).

Comment: Solar hydronic heating is also common where I live in Colorado, USA. Although, PV powered heat pumps seem to be more popular for new construction.

Comment: You are stating the obvious here. A solar thermal collector is rated at 1.7-2.5kw for the same area that is rated 250-300w for a solar panel. Obviously, a ~2/10 collection rate is expected. Selling points are, cost is low, installation is there, the system is hybrid so on days with little-no sunlight i can still swap to electric with the flip of a switch, the boiler is inside where its already warm so no extra losses on cold days.

Answer (score 2):

### PSA: High voltage DC is *dangerous*

OK first, 240V >>DC<< is nothing to fool around with.  The nature of DC power changes dramatically at such high voltages.  It is much more dangerous than the equivalent AC power.  Just look at power handling equipment - you will see the DC rating is much lower than the AC rating.  240 volt AC equipment is found at any home store. 240V DC equipment is either expensive industrial/specialty, or cheap dangerous Chinesium.

So you should be handling any power above about 50V as AC, not DC.  And you should still use all the precautions required by your country's or modern electrical codes for that AC power.

### So how about this: use a 120V AC inverter. And a diode.

Now, water heaters are simple resistors. With resistor heaters, if you halve the voltage, you quarter the power.  It's designed for 4000W @ 240VAC, but at 120VAC, it's only 1000W.

120VAC inverters are readily available.

**Now, what happens if you run 120VAC through a diode?**  You get half power, since only half the sinewave is actually coming through.  **Now we are at 500W @ 120V.**

"That was easy" :)

Now all you need is a 120V inverter that responds to low voltage by shutting off for 8 seconds.

Comment: How does a typical inverter respond to being half-wave-rectified at rated power?  Low power is probably fine, but I would guess that it's still more stressful than simply a lower resistance.  Do that at rated power, and I don't think it would like you at all!

Comment: A diode to a resistor is the most non-inductive load imaginable, so everything with it happens in real time.  So how would the inverter *even know*?  It doesn't have a memory, not even a 10ms one.  It's simply seeing the load change, which an inverter better be able to handle, but again, no memory, so no concept of "change". @AaronD   As for sizing, that's a product selection issue. I wouldn't expect anything but magic smoke from a Chinesium inverter run at rated power to *any* load.

Comment: Having many years ago taken a foolish shock from a beefy 200VDC lab supply, I can concur that serious DC electrocution is scary as hell - a totally different beast than AC!

Comment: what really throws people is how docile and well-behaved 5V and 12VDC is, it's like a labrador retriever of voltages. They don't appreciate how sharply DC turns into a rabid wolverine at higher voltages.  Once a DC arc starts, it cannot be bargained with, it cannot be reasoned with, it does not feel pity or remorse or fear...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Output transformer???  A (very) naive design might use a 12V, 50 or 60Hz oscillator to drive a 1:10 60Hz tranny.  That has memory, in the form of a massive DC offset on the secondary.  And who knows what someone else might decide to do inside of their "black box".  Some would be just fine, others probably not.

Comment: @AaronD Not likely in a consumer product.  Physics dictates that the size of a transformer's ferric core is a function of AC frequency. 50/60 Hz requires *positively enormous* cores by electronics standards.  A 1 KVA transformer runs about 27 pounds/12kg.  No way around it except using aluminum wire, and that'll only shave a couple pounds. The metal value alone is considerable.